# Aligning assembly version numbers with TFS Buildnumber

Tags: tfs, msbuild, versioning

I am wondering if there is a way to synchronize the build numbers (20080213.1) without using the BuildNumberOverrideTarget where I would have to generate my own build number? I basically want to use the default/built-in tfs buildnumber generator but want to access it to align my assembly versions with it. Can this be done and is it a sensible way to do it this way?

Answer (score 10):

What you are asking for is very sensible and there are a number of ways to achieve this.

Personally, when I do this I don't like to check the files in to version control that have the build server generated number in them - it just introduces too many head-aches when merging code across branches but also I like a known version number to be used when a developer does a workstation build vs a proper build server derived assembly to make it really easy to tell them apart.

For more information on how I like to do it, take a look at the TFS Build Recipies wiki:

- [TFS Build: Assembly Versioning](http://www.tfsbuild.com/AssemblyVersioning%20.ashx)

or my blog post on the topic

- [Martin Woodward: Aligning Build Numbers with Assembly Versions](http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/000417.html)

Hope that helps,

Martin.

Comment: Thank you Martin. I had already come across your excellent post on the alignment and have used that method. When you say you like a known version number to be used on developer builds you mean that those would be the ones from the assembly info file without any overrides? say 1.0.0.0?

Comment: For developers do you only use the VS build or do you use build scripts that developers should use on their workstations?

Comment: For developers I only use the VS build.  I sometimes use Developer Workstation builds using the TeamBuild script - however VS builds tend to be able to do the job 90% of the time and makes things much simpler.

In answer to your earlier comment, I indeed use 1.0.0.0 in the AssemblyInfo files.

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can.  At some point, possibly at AfterGet, you can use the BuildNumber and create a custom task to update the AssemblyInfo.cs files in your source code.

We've hooked into AfterGet and caused our target to be dependant:

```
<Target Name="AfterGet" DependsOnTargets="VersionAssemblies" />
```

Our VersionAssemblies Target pulls all of the AssemblyInfo.cs files from $(SolutionRoot):

```
<CreateItem Include="$(SolutionRoot)\**\AssemblyInfo.cs;">
    <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="AssemblyInfos"/>
 </CreateItem>
```

checks them out:

```
<Exec Command="$(TfCommand) checkout &quot;AssemblyInfo.cs&quot; -r"
          WorkingDirectory="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\sources" ContinueOnError="true"/>
```

edits them and replaces the file version with the $(BuildNumber):

```
<File.Replace Path="%(AssemblyInfos.FullPath)"
                  NewValue="AssemblyFileVersion(&quot;$(BuildNumber)&quot;)"
                  RegularExpression="AssemblyFileVersion\(\&quot;(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)\&quot;\)"
                  IgnoreCase="true"
                  Force="true"/>
```

and then checks the files back in:

```
<Exec Command="$(TfCommand) checkin /override:&quot;Automated&quot; /comment:&quot;Update AssemblyInfo files to version number $(BuildNumber) - $(NoCICheckinComment) &quot; /noprompt &quot;AssemblyInfo.cs&quot; /recursive"
          WorkingDirectory="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\sources" ContinueOnError="false"/>
```

For the replacement of the file versions I use the File.Replace task that comes with the Microsoft [SDC tasks](http://www.codeplex.com/sdctasks) on CodePlex.

Also note, that if you have a build that is triggered on a checkin, when checking in the AssemblyInfo.cs files, make sure the comment includes $(NoCICheckinComment) as this causes TFS not to trigger another build otherwise you'll end up in an infinite build loop.

Comment: How do you pull the build and revision from $(BuildNumber) as it is by default of the format "MyBuildDefinition_20090213.1"?

Comment: You could write a custom task to strip out the MyBuildDefinition_ part and strip it out.