# MSBuild, Extension Pack and TfsVersion

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild, tfsbuild, msbuildcommunitytasks

I am trying to implement what I see in this post: [TFS and msbuild version number with last changeset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630823/tfs-and-msbuild-version-number-with-last-changeset).  That is, I am trying to get the last Changeset number at build time so I can use it in an AssemblyVersionInfo.cs.

I am using VS 2008 and TFS 2008.  I have installed MSBuild Extension pack v3.5.9.0 (x64).  It is in C:\Program Files\MSBuild\ExtensionPack.  Here is my MSBuild project:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="3.5" DefaultTargets="Default" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="C:\Program Files\MSBuild\ExtensionPack\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks"/>
  <Target Name="Default">
    <TfsVersion  TfsLibraryLocation="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies"
                 LocalPath="$(SolutionRoot)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Changeset" PropertyName="ChangesetNumber"/>
    </TfsVersion>
    <Message Text="TFS ChangeSetNumber: $(ChangesetNumber)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Here is how I am running the script:

```
C:\Build\TeamBuildTypes\Nightly_Main>MSbuild test.proj
```

Here is my error message:

```
C:\Build\TeamBuildTypes\Nightly_Main\test.proj(4,5): error MSB4062: The "MSBuild.ExtensionPack.VisualStudio.TfsVersion" task could not be loaded from the asse
mbly C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\ExtensionPack\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\ExtensionPack\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, and that the assembly and all its dependencies are available.
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: Sounds obvious, but... does that file actually exist on the build machine?  Is it maybe a 32-bit OS.  Have you looked at the fusion log to see if it is a dependency issue?

Comment: version attributes numbers are limited to uint16 so while this approach is good you will eventually fail to version your assemblies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks is trying to find libraries not where they are located. You can open this file and add this in the top of the file

```
<ExtensionTasksPath>C:\Program Files\MSBuild\ExtensionPack\</ExtensionTasksPath>
```

in place of other `ExtensionTasksPath` declarations (just comment them and add this). This should fix the paths problem.
I assume that there exists `C:\Program Files\MSBuild\ExtensionPack\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.dll`