# It is possible to get TFS change set number from the local file system?

Tags: version-control, tfs

I have a local copy of a solution. It is bound to TFS

Is possible to derive the current change set information from the local file system without doing a call to the server?

Comment: What do you mean, "current change set"?

Comment: @JohnSaunders each checkin results in a changeset.

Comment: I know TFS very well. You haven't explained what you mean by "current".

Comment: @JohnSaunders sorry. as in what changeset you have retrieved from the server

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround, if you can use the Revision number in the `[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.RevisionNumber")]` you could set the change set information there.

[Aligning assembly version numbers with TFS Buildnumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545566/aligning-assembly-version-numbers-with-tfs-buildnumber), this way each time you build, each projects AssemblyInfo.cs would contain the change set info. Admittedly this would be project-wide, not file specific.

After some more research I found this thread and its seems very close:
[TFS and msbuild version number with last changeset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630823/tfs-and-msbuild-version-number-with-last-changeset)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but rather a long comment. That's why I've marked it as CW.

Here's a thought experiment:

Pick a time, any time. Determine the latest changeset as of that time. Call it "cs".

How do you know that there isn't a later changeset checked in just seconds after you figured out "cs"?

Without connectivity to the server, there can be no simultaneity.

Comment: I dont care about what is on the server. I want stamp the assembly with the changeset information.

Comment: Ok, got it. The answer is "no". TFS keeps no source control information on the local disk.

Comment: while we are here is it possible to detect pending changes?